# Use of the to explain a behavior

Tags: grammar, sentence, sentence-meaning

Please check if there is a repitition of **the** here

The model can be used to investigate the frequency dependent behavior of **the** Sinusoidal signal

How about,

The model can be used to investigate the frequency dependent behavior of Sinusoidal signal

Since I am anchoring **the** at the behavior of the signal

Thanks

Comment: *Which* sinusoidal signal??

Comment: That's not a good question

Comment: 'The Taming of Shrew'? 'The Lord of Rings'? 'The Hunting of Snark'? 'The Day of Triffids'?

Comment: @Sam - Quite the contrary.  That's *the* question.

Comment: Well you can think of it as a particular signal. Like a signal characterized by its frequency and phase.

Comment: So, "**a** particular signal?